# After migrating a Play 2.2.x application to allow deployment as a war using the play2war plugin, how do I start it again using "run"

Tags: playframework-2.2

After migrating the project layout to the requirements of the [play2war plugin](https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin). how do I run the application again using Play's `run` command?

#### Background

`play2war` required me to move all sources from their 'normal' location in the folder structure into a new sub-folder `common`. Also, the standard file `conf/application.conf` was replaced with an empty one 'to make Play happy again' (quoted from the [sample application](https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin/tree/develop/sample) provided with `play2war`)

#### Symptoms

Now I can start the application with the `run` command, but it seems to be an empty shell. Any URL I enter into my browser results in an 'Action not found' error.

How can I configure Play to find my sources in this new `common` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When migrating the project to `play2war`, I was asked to define in total four sub-projects: `<appName>common` and three more for the various servlet versions supported (`2.5`, `3.0`, and `3.1`), e.g. `<appName>servlet25`.

Running the application using Play is simply a matter of selecting the 'common' project (at Play's shell prompt):

`project <appName>common`

After that, `run` works as expected.